# ReactJs Row and Column

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J29O5.png)

After I fetch the data from database and display it, how to I make it only show 4 columns 2 rows and a nagivation to show other data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to implement pagination for showing 8 items per page.
And should set the display property of panel style to **grid**.
Reference this [Specifying the columns in a grid](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#specifying-the-columns-in-a-grid)

```
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```